# dropdown select value in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am currently trying to create a sample shopping site,The problem came when I created a search page.In my search page I Have two fields one for enter the keyword and other for select type of item
Which means search,[image]keyword in the selected item.but the item defined in DB is 0 and 1 and i Trying to get it my code but fails...could any one help me...

The Gfunction code is

```
    public static function item(){
    $optionList='';
$CategoryList = OfferEvents::model()->findAllByAttributes(array());

foreach($CategoryList as $catdata)
{   $optionList.="<option value='".$catdata['type']."'>".$catdata['name']."</option>";     }
return $optionList; 

}
```

and view code is

```
    <form action="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/offer?>" method="GET"  class="form-inline form-section-2 row  fadeInDown animated">
  <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
    <input type="text"  name="search"  class="form-control" id="search" value="" placeholder="Enter Your Keyword">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
       <select  name="cat" class="form-control selectpicker">
        <option value='0'>Select type</option>
        <?php echo GFunctions::item(); ?>
        </select> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-new">Search</button>    
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code....

**Function**

```
public static function item(){
    $CategoryList = OfferEvents::model()->findAllByAttributes(array());

    $optionList = CHtml::listData($countries, 'type', 'name')
    return $optionList; 
}
```

**In view**

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('cat', '', GFunctions::item(), array('prompt'=>'Select type'));?>
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use Yii built in functions to handle the dropdown?
I am not sure how your Models looks like but you can choose one of the following functions to achieve what you want instead of trying to return a String $optionList with HTML tags.

[CHtml::activeDropDownList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail)  // for directly bind to active record model

[CHtml::dropDownList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail)